# Create a pointer to a function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Is it possible to create a pointer to a function pointer, i.e.

```
int32_t (*fp[2])(void) = {test_function1, test_function_2}; // initialize a function pointer

<unknown> = fp;
```

What needs to be written in place of unknown? With "normal" arrays, I could do this:

```
int a[2] = {0, 1};

int* p = a;
```

Comment: Why do you declare `fp` as an array of function pointers, if you only want a single pointer?

Comment: As for your problem, you need to declare a variable that is a *pointer to an array* of function pointers, the *pointer to an array* is the important parts here. And if that's not what you want, then we can't help you unless you tell us *what* you want? And possibly *why* you want it (read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: The size of the function pointer array shall be irrelevant.

Comment: The problem is that the size *isn't* irrelevant, especially if you want to declare a pointer to an array.

Comment: `int32_t (**fpp)(void) = fp;`

Comment: But I want only a pointer which shall point to the first element of the arrray.

Comment: Have you *tried* just declaring `<unknown>` as a plain pointer to a function? Remember that arrays decays to pointers to their first element, in your case `fp` decays to a pointer to `test_function1`.

Comment: Yes, the compiler complains "assignment from incompatible pointer type".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
typedef void(*func_ptr_t)(void); // a function pointer

func_ptr_t* ptr_to_func_ptr;     // a pointer to a function pointer - easy to read
func_ptr_t  arr[2];              // an array of function pointers - easy to read

void(**func_ptr_ptr)(void);      // a pointer to a function pointer - hard to read
void(*func_ptr_arr [2])(void);   // an array of function pointers - hard to read
```

Comment: if I have void (**foo)(int, int) as a pointer to a function pointer. How can the function pointer be use ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564473/pointer-to-a-function-a-different-approach-of-declaring

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef int32_t FP(void);

FP *fp[2] = { test_function1, test_function2 };
FP **p = fp;
```

Comment: Personally I would probably make the type-alias `FP` a pointer, but that's just a matter of personal taste. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I would do that too, function pointers is about the only case where it is ok to hide a pointer behind a typedef. But I think the style in this answer is fine too, since it is consistent with the rule of never typedef:ing away a pointer.

Comment: This way you can also declare functions, e.g. `FP test_function1, test_function2;`

Comment: @MattMcNabb That, I would however not recommend, as it will make the reader confuse them with variables. You'd easily make the mistake of declaring a function at local scope, for example.