# Pointer to a function - A different approach of declaring

Tags: c, pointers

While reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c) (the answer given by psychotic), I understood how to typedef and call a function pointer. But after thinking about typedefs I experimented with them a little and was able to call functions this way also:

```
typedef void func(unsigned char);
void test(unsigned char a);

int main()
{
    unsigned char b=0U;
    func *fp=&test;
    while(1)
    {
        fp(b);
        b++;
    }
}

void test(unsigned char a)
{
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

I don't get what is the the difference between using the function pointer syntax and this approach? Both seem to almost yield the same functionality.

Comment: Are you under the impression that function pointers aren't involved here? You're making function pointers; it's just a slightly different syntax.

Comment: What do you think `func *fp` is, if not a function pointer?

Comment: How is this *"without function pointer"*?

Comment: So this is a method without using function pointers syntax?

Comment: I edited the question to be clear

Comment: You *are* using function pointer syntax; you're just moving the pointer part to the var decl rather than the typedef alias you seem accustomed to.

Comment: No, `func *fp=&test;` is still function pointer syntax, just with a different typedef. You've literally just moved the `*` from the typedef to the local variable decl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The style

```
typedef void func_t (void);
...
funct_t* fp;
```

Is one of the clearest ways to declare function pointers. Clear because it is consistent with the rest of the pointer syntax of C.

It is equivalent to the slightly less readable

```
typedef void (*func_t)(void);
func_t fp;
```

Which in turn is equivalent to the much less readable

```
void (*fp)(void);
```

The advantage of the first style becomes obvious when you pass these as parameters to a function:

```
1) void sort (func_t* callback);      // very clear and readable!
2) void sort (func_t callback);       // hmm what is this? passing by value?
3) void sort (void(*callback)(void)); // unreadable mess
```

Generally, it is a bad idea to hide the pointer syntax behind typedefs. Function pointers are no exception.

Comment: I thought so. Because its very easy to interpret(or i have gotten used to) something like UINT8 *u8ptr as a pointer that is pointing to a type occupying 8 bits of memory. Equivalent function pointer version for your 1st case would be interpreted as: a pointer that is pointing to the type funct_t(which is a function taking no parameters and returning nothing).

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a function pointer with the declaration i.e.

```
func *fp = &test; // fp is a function pointer!
```

The other way would be to typedef the pointer,

```
typedef void (*func)(unsigned char);
func fp = &test; // Notice, no '*' in the declaration?
```

Comment: So im just moving the * around. The syntax still remains

Comment: for `typedef void (func)(unsigned char);` is right or not?

Answer (score 1):

If `func` were `typedef`ed as function pointer then the statement

```
func *fp=&test;
```

would be

```
func fp=&test;
```