# Use case of function pointers in c

Tags: c, function, pointers

One of the common use cases I've come across when I read about function pointers is  that they can be used to make a function more flexible, as part of the functionality of the function can be taken in as a parameter. An example for this is qsort where I can make a compare function to decide what is meant by greater and lesser (ascending, descending, is a multiple of,etc) and pass the compare funtion pointer to qsort function.

Here, the function repeat has addptr as parameter and therefore performs multiplication.

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int (*addptr)(int,int);

int repeat(int a,int b,int (*funcptr)(int,int))
{
    int i,ans=0;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        ans=(*funcptr)(ans,b);
    }
    return ans;
}


int main()
{
    addptr=&add;
    printf("%d\n",repeat(7,5,addptr));  

    return 0;

}
```

But the same exact thing can be done without function pointers at all!

```
int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }


    int repeat(int a,int b,int func(int,int))
    {
        int i,ans=0;
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            ans=func(ans,b);
        }
        return ans;
    }


    int main()
    {
        printf("%d\n",repeat(7,5,add)); 

        return 0;

    }
```

So why is this even one of the uses of function pointers?
What is the advantage of the first code over the second?

Comment: "Function type" decays to "function pointer type" in function parameters

Comment: `What is the advantage of the first code over the second?` You need to find use cases that apply to that. That's a very broad scenario, IMHO.

Comment: You are doing the same thing in both

Comment: If your use is fixed, you don't need function pointers. If your use is variable or can change (in design) over time, you may consider it.

Comment: Function pointers allow passing functions as parameters (aka [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)). I think the best way to understand the power of passing functions as parameters (function composition, closures, etc...) is to try some functional language, it will give you a good insight about why there are function pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a rule C11 6.7.6.3/8 saying that if you write a function inside a parameter list, it will get adjusted to a pointer to function of that type:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be
>   adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’,

This works similar to when you write an array as function parameter, it gets adjusted to a pointer to the first element.

That being said, it is not really meaningful to write a function as a parameter, it is just very confusing to the reader. Use function pointers instead.

---

EDIT

For maximum readability, I would personally recommend using this style:

```
typedef int operation_t (int, int);

int repeat (int a, int b, operation_t* operation)
{ ...
```

Though the most commonly used style is perhaps this one:

```
typedef int (*operation_t) (int, int);

int repeat (int a, int b, operation_t operation)
{ ...
```

I prefer the former since hiding pointers behind typedefs is a bad idea, and since that style makes function pointers consistent with regular pointers.

Comment: So, here internally, add and func are the same as addptr and funcptr?

Comment: It is purely syntactic sugar. Many (myself included) find it easier to read the code if you use the function syntax.

Comment: Readability is a poor argument though, since the most readable form uses a typedef. I added some examples to the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564473/pointer-to-a-function-a-different-approach-of-declaring

Answer (score 0):

As noticed in comment by @user2390668, `func` in repeat in already a function pointer. And when you call it, `add` *decays* to a function pointer.

If your question is what is a possible use case for a variable holding a function pointer, we must try to imagine a use case where a function will not only be passed as a parameter, but will have to be stored. An example for that would be *simulating* polymorphism of structs in C. Here is an oversimplified example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Base {
    /* common member variables
    ...
    */
    const char *name;
    void (*display)(void *, FILE *fd);
};

struct S1 {
    struct Base base;
    /* other member variables */
};

void _S1_display(void *this, FILE *fd) {
    struct S1 *s1 = this;
    fprintf(fd, "In S1, name: %s\n", s1->base.name);
}

struct S2 {
    struct Base base;
    /* other member variables */
};

void _S2_display(void *this, FILE *fd) {
    struct S2 *s2 = this;
    fprintf(fd, "In S1, name: %s\n", s2->base.name);
}

void process(void *this, FILE *fd) {
    struct Base *base = this; /* valid because base is first element of both S1 and S2 */
    base->display(this, fd);
}

int main() {
    struct S1 s1 = { "s1", &_S1_display };
    struct S2 s2 = { "s2", &_S2_display };

    process(&s1, stdout);
    process(&s2, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, fur such a simply example, polymorphism would not be necessary, but as I said it is oversimplified...

Answer (score 0):

You may use pointers to functions when you need a little more abstraction.
For example, you may want to manage a table of operators that a *generic* function should use:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
int sub(int a, int b) {
    return a-b;
}
int mult(int a, int b) {
    return a*b;
}
int div(int a, int b) {
    return a/b;
}

void doit(int a,int b,int (*ptr[2])(int,int)) {
    printf("%d\n",ptr[0](a,b));
    printf("%d\n",ptr[1](a,b));
}


int main() {
    int (*ptr[2])(int,int);
    printf("additives (1) or multiplicatives (2) ?");
    int choice;
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
          ptr[0] = &add;
          ptr[1] = &sub;
          break;
        default:
          ptr[0] = &mult;
          ptr[1] = &div;
          break;
    }
    doit(7,5,ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course you can also design a `doit` function with two pointers but sometimes a table is more convenient (think about a variable length table of function pointers for example, I know even in this case we may use a variable arguments list...).

At least, passing a function pointer in parameter is defining a function pointer variable...

Another example is also implementing in C object oriented programming, where you may implement methods as function pointers members.